# How to handle the user from Keys.Escape and click the mouse so it doesn't select outside the combobox autocomplete list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autocomplete, keyboard

I'm trying  to handle the user from Keys.Escape and click the mouse so it doesn't select outside the combobox autocomplete list in vb.net

in the code below I disabled it for `Keys.Escape`

if there are any other suggestions or recommendations

Please Guide Me

```
Public Class Form2
    Private bindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private COLORCODESERVICE As New ColorcodeService()
    Private Sub BindcomboboxColorCode()
        Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Colorcode"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Colorcode"
        bindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ColorCode)(CType(COLORCODESERVICE.GetByColorcode(), IList(Of ColorCode)))}
        ComboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        BindcomboboxColorCode()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
        If Not Me.ComboBox1.IsHandleCreated Then Return
        Me.AutoComplete(Me.ComboBox1, e, True)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal k As Keys) As Boolean
        If k = Keys.Escape Then
            Me.ComboBox1 = Nothing
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, k)
    End Function
    '' AutoComplete
    'Public Sub AutoComplete(ByVal cb As ComboBox, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    '    Me.AutoComplete(cb, e, False)
    'End Sub
    Public Sub AutoComplete(ByVal cb As ComboBox, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, ByVal blnLimitToList As Boolean)
        Dim strFindStr As String = ""

        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
            If cb.SelectionStart <= 1 Then
                cb.Text = ""
                Return
            End If

            If cb.SelectionLength = 0 Then
                strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.Text.Length - 1)
            Else
                strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart - 1)
            End If
        Else
            If cb.SelectionLength = 0 Then
                strFindStr = cb.Text & e.KeyChar
            Else
                strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart) & e.KeyChar
            End If
        End If

        Dim intIdx As Integer = -1

        ' Search the string in the ComboBox list.

        intIdx = cb.FindString(strFindStr)

        If intIdx <> -1 Then
            cb.SelectedText = ""
            cb.SelectedIndex = intIdx
            cb.SelectionStart = strFindStr.Length
            cb.SelectionLength = cb.Text.Length
            e.Handled = True
        Else
            'e.Handled = blnLimitToList
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ColorcodeService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetByColorcode() As IEnumerable(Of ColorCode)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT ColorCode FROM ColorCode"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ColorCode)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class ColorCode
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Colorname() As String
End Class
```

the results of the code above are in gif

[image: the results of the code above are in gif]

Update answer use combobox validating

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
        If ComboBox1.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso
           Not String.Equals(ComboBox1.Text,
                             ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem),
                             StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a value from the ComboBox.", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are over complicating the solution. Consider using a `DropDownList` - no other input allowed. Or, validate the input matches pre-approved values.

Comment: Just handle the `Validating` event and don't let the control oose focus if the `Text` doesn't match an item. Don't make things harder for yourself than they need to be.

Comment: @JayV , Thank you for your reply,  `Consider using a DropDownList`  for this I was attracted using the dropdownstyle  `Dropdown` . For this ` validate the input matches pre-approved values` please guide me and I've also updated on posting using events   `validating`but messagebox appears if I close form what is wrong I want messagebox at that time to be invalid

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Just handle the Validating event and don't let the control oose focus if the Text doesn't match an item. `  I've also updated on posting using events `validating` but messagebox appears if I close form what is wrong I want messagebox at that time to be invalid.  Please Guide Me